# Sequelize : How to config webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, sequelize.js

I'm using react and node js. I want to use Sequelize to manage database with mysql. 
So I have this tree with sequelize :

[image]

In my package config, I have this : 
[image]

So when i do :

```
npm run seed
```

I want execute the code of sequelize in seed folder. 
But I have an error in node console : 
[image]

How can I correct this error ? 
Thank you